# AntlrWorks 2 output

Tags: antlrworks, antlrworks2

So i am using Antlrworks 2, working on a rather large grammar. Problem is that in this grammar there are multiple ambiguities that i am trying to work through.

I was wondering if there is a way to interpret which rules were invoked when there was a failure.

For instance, when i run my rule i get following output

```
[@0,0:1='99',<20>,1:0]
[@1,2:1='<EOF>',<-1>,1:2]
line 1:0 mismatched input '99' expecting Digit2
(dummy 99)
```

I am wondering what `[@0,0:1='99',<20>,1:0]` means. Do the `@0` or `<20>` have any relationship to the rule number in my grammar or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a breakdown of the default token formatting.

```
[@{TokenIndex},{StartIndex}:{StopIndex}={Text},<{TokenType}>,{Line}:{Column}]
```

The `{TokenType}` field generally corresponds to a particular lexer rule (the constant will be declared in your generated lexer). However, the `-> type(X)` command can be used in any lexer rule to reassign tokens produced by that rule to another type. If the value `20` is assigned to the token named `Foo`, then the first token in your listing was produced by *either* a lexer rule named `Foo` *or* a lexer rule containing the action `-> type(foo)` *or* you have a user-defined action which explicitly assigns the type `Foo` to a token produced by some other rule (this will be code you wrote, not code generated by ANTLR).